# How to set a Select value based on <a> click

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I have a MVC View with a few images, each image has a link that links to a Form that is located on the bottom of the View, the Form has a `<select>` filed that has to be populated based on the clicked link.

This is the `div` on the top of the page  with the images and the links:

```
<div class="propImg"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <a href="#lnkForm" class="serviceRequest">Customer Service Request</a>
</div>
<div class="propImg"><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <a href="#lnkForm" class="serviceRequest">Customer Service Request</a>
</div>
```

And this is the `form` in the bottom of the page:

```
<form id="formProperties">
   <select id="properties" name="properties" class="required simple-dropdown txtbox">
     <option value="">Select a Property</option>
     <option value="1">100 Central Avenue</option>
     <option value="2">220 Central Avenue</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

This is the JavaScript function that on `<a>` click toggles the page and takes the user to the `form`:

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function () {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
        if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

I'm not sure how to populate the `<select>` based on the link that the user clicks.
For example: If the user clicked on the first link the `<select>` should now has the `1` value, if the second `<a>`- the `<select>` should be set with `2` etc...

Any advice?

The divs of the images and the links look like that: (I removed some design elements to shorten it but I see it is necessary...)

```
<div>
        <div class="propImg"><img src="images/1-test-RoadL.jpg" alt="" /></div>
        <span class="txt15">
            <br>
            <strong>1 test Road</strong><br>
            Piscataway, NJ
        </span>
        <span class="state">
            <br>
            12,477 SF<br>
        </span><br>
        <a href="#lnkForm" class="serviceRequest">Customer Service Request</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to get selected select based on the click on the image?

Comment: Exactly. If the first `<a>` was clicked the `<select>` should gets the value `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$('.serviceRequest').on('click',function (e) {
    var q = $(this);
    var target = q.index('.serviceRequest')+1;
    $("#properties option[value="+target+"]").prop("selected","selected");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

And the example here : https://jsfiddle.net/synz/3s5jgr1o/1/

Comment: Updated. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Working perfectly! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery you may create your own plugin for that

```js
// Plugin
(function($){
  $.fn.selectify = function(){
    return this.click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var $this = $(this);
      var target = $this.attr('data-target');
      var val = $this.attr('data-selectify');
      $(target).val(val);
    });
  };
  
  // auto init for all elements which has 'data-selectify' attribute
  $(function(){
    $('[data-selectify]').selectify();
  });
  
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test-select">
  <option value="" selected>Select</option>
  <option value="1">Value 1</option>
  <option value="2">Value 2</option>
</select>
<br />
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-selectify="1" data-target="#test-select">Click to select 1</a>
<br />
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-selectify="2" data-target="#test-select">Click to select 2</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link has been clicked img filename can be got and based on the img name select option can be selected using below line of code.

```
var filename = $(this).prev().find('img').attr('src').split('/').pop().split('.')[0];
```

Please check below working snippet.

```js
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function () {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
        if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        }
    }
  
    //Get filename from img tag based on the link clicked
    var filename = $(this).prev().find('img').attr('src').split('/').pop().split('.')[0];
    //Get selected option based on the link has been clicked.
    $("#properties").val(filename)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="propImg"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <a href="#lnkForm" class="serviceRequest">Customer Service Request</a>
</div>
<div class="propImg"><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <a href="#lnkForm" class="serviceRequest">Customer Service Request</a>
</div>

<form id="formProperties">
   <select id="properties" name="properties" class="required simple-dropdown txtbox">
     <option value="">Select a Property</option>
     <option value="1">100 Central Avenue</option>
     <option value="2">220 Central Avenue</option>
   </select>
</form>
```